# array rank and group by in a SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Team

Greetings!

Here is my BigQuery table.

```
customer     state        questions          response_displayed       datetime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john         NY           q1                 answer1,answer2,answer3   22-jan
jack         NJ           q2                 answer1,answer2,answer3   23-jan
mario        OH           q3                 answer1,answer2           24-jan  
john         NY           q4                 answer1,answer120         25-jan
jack         NJ           q5                 answer2                   26-jan
```

Here I am trying to sum all questions asked by a customer, state combination, and get the most frequent response_displayed. we have to split & unnest response_dispalyed and then take the count of each response and get the 1st rank.

Here is the sample output

```
customer       state              total_question        frequent_response_dispalyed
john           ny                 2                     answer1 
jack           nj                 2                     answer2 
mario          oh                 1                     answer1,answer2
```

I am unable to use the unnest(split(response_dispalyed)) along with the group by function.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: customer state questions response_displayed            datetime
john      NY   q1        answer1,answer2,answer3        22-jan 
jack      NJ   q2        answer1,answer2,answer3        23-jan 
mario     OH   q3        answer1,answer2                 24-jan
john      NY   q4        answer1,answer120              25-jan 
jack      NJ   q5        answer2                                 26-jan

Comment: expected result                                                                                                         
 customer state total_questions top_response                                                                     john NY 2 answer1                                                                                                           jack NJ 2 answer2                                                                                                         mario OH 1 answer1,answer2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(responses),
  array_to_string(array(
    select response from (
      select response, count(*) frequency
      from unnest(responses) response
      group by response
    )
    where true
    qualify rank() over(order by frequency desc) = 1
  ), ',') as frequent_response_dispalyed
from (
  select customer, state, count(*) as total_question,
    array_concat_agg(split(response_displayed)) as responses
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by customer, state
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)